# Polynomial form of certain linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I have encountered an interesting problem while reading *Advanced Linear Algebra* by S. Roman (3rd ed., chapter 3, ex. 21).

> Let $\text{dim}(V)<\infty$. If $\tau, \sigma \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ prove
>   that $\sigma\tau = \iota$ implies that $\tau$ and $\sigma$ are
>   invertible and that $\sigma = p(\tau)$ for some polynomial 
>   $p(x) \in F[x]$.

Obviously, the first part of the statement is trivial. The second part is equally easy, provided that one knows how to apply the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem.

The problem is that the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem was introduced in a further chapter. There is little doubt the author intended this statement to be proved without referring to any notion of eigenvalues, characteristic polynomials, etc. And herein lies my problem -- I cannot think of anything more straightforward to prove this theorem.

I would appreciate any hints.